# Extra White Space in Horizontal Scrollview of UITableViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiedgeinsets

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"d944f7"]];
    self.pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - 20, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    self.scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
}

- (void)reloadData
{
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = self.sectionsArray.count;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(rand()%256)/256.0 green:(rand()%256)/256.0 blue:(rand()%256)/256.0 alpha:1];
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(rand()%256)/256.0 green:(rand()%256)/256.0 blue:(rand()%256)/256.0 alpha:1];
    self.pageControl.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.0, self.view.frame.size.height - 20);
    self.pageControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageControl];
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width*self.pageControl.numberOfPages, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *mvcs = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *shadows = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < self.pageControl.numberOfPages; i ++) {
        UIView *shadow = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width - 20, self.scrollView.frame.size.height - 80)];
        shadow.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        shadow.alpha = 1;
        CGPoint pageCenter = CGPointMake((i + 0.5)*self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height/2.0);
        shadow.center = pageCenter;
       // [shadows addObject:shadow];
        //[self.scrollView addSubview:shadow];

        MDIMovingView *mv = [[MDIMovingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width - 5, self.scrollView.frame.size.height - 80)];
        mv.identity = 1;
        mv.delegate = self;
        mv.moveEnabled=NO;
        mv.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"e6e6e6"];
        mv.center = pageCenter;
        mv.layer.cornerRadius=10;
        mv.clipsToBounds=NO;
        [array addObject:mv];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:mv];


        UIView *topHeader=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, mv.frame.size.width, 50)];

        [topHeader setRoundedCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight radius:10.0];
        [topHeader setBackgroundColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"dca2e8"]];
        [mv addSubview:topHeader];

        UIView *invisibleSeperator =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, mv.frame.size.width, 2)];
        [invisibleSeperator setBackgroundColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"d944f7"]];
        [mv addSubview:invisibleSeperator];


        MDITableViewController *vc = [[MDITableViewController alloc] init];
        [mvcs addObject:vc];

        vc.objects = self.sortedTasksArray[i];
        vc.delegate = self;
        vc.dataSoure = self;
        vc.movingViewDelegate = self;
        [self addChildViewController:vc];
        vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(5, 60, mv.frame.size.width - 10, mv.frame.size.height - 80);
        [mv addSubview:vc.view];
    }
    self.shadowViews = shadows;
    self.movingViews = array;
    self.tableVCs = mvcs;
}
```

Here is what its doing- note the space between navigation bar and the movingview:

[image]

Comment: Your code has many hardcoded values. Could it be the `60` in the frame of your `MDITableViewController`? You should try to remove as many unnecessary details from your code before posting, to make it easier to track down the problem.

Comment: Something odd that happens is when i reduce the -80 from movingview to say -40  for the height it not only gets longer but it moves up making me think there is something auto centering the movingviews in the scrollview?

Answer (score -2):

You have to disable the automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets in your view controller

```
[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
```

**or in Storyboard**
Uncheck the option

[image]

Comment: 1. all done programmatically
2. I already have that code in my code I posted.

Comment: and please dont downvote me just bc you did not take the time to read and/or dont have a good answer.